# Workflow for Working on Moodle As a Team

Tags: moodle

I and a friend want to work, remotely, on a Moodle website. I have got the application installed locally, but I'm not sure what I need to commit into our `git` repository and what I shouldn't.

I'm looking for a workflow that allows someone to clone the code, run a CLI command or something, and be up and running. Since our machines are development machines, I"m trying to lower the number of steps (ie, we can both just share the same configuration file).

Comment: Are you developing the code for the site, or the content?
If it is the code, then don't commit the config file - it takes about 5 min to set up a new Moodle site, including generating a local config file.
If it is the content you are working on, then that will be much more difficult to manage - you will have to work on courses then backup & restore to the 'live' site.

Comment: You may also want to look at 'Moosh' for automating the creation of courses & users for the dev site - https://github.com/tmuras/moosh

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yeah, I'm working on the code, but I'll probably put in some initial content as well. For example, when I disable something (E.G. when I disable comments or blogs), I don't want to have to go into the production website after I first deploy the application, and do the whole setup all over again. If Moosh does this stuff, can you please give an answer instead of a comment so that I can accept it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to take a look at Moosh ( https://github.com/tmuras/moosh ).

This can script-up a lot of the things I think you want to do (set settings, create courses + users, etc).

You could then create a command-line script that would call Moosh and prepare a lot of the settings that you will eventually want on your live site (what it cannot do is take the settings from an existing site and apply them automatically to a new site).